# Xamarin Android: Facebook share content is empty

Tags: facebook, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin Forms App. Which I created a FBShareButton : Button to handle the sharing via custom renderers. This is the code in my renderer:

```
public class FacebookShareRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{   
    ShareButton sb;
    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);
        sb = new ShareButton(Context);

        this.Control.Click += (sender, eargs) => sb.PerformClick();
        sb.Click += (sender, eargs) => {
                ShareLinkContent.Builder shareLinkContentBuilder = new ShareLinkContent.Builder().
                    SetContentDescription("Hello").
                    SetContentTitle("Desc");
                shareLinkContentBuilder.SetImageUrl("url");
                ShareLinkContent shareLinkContent = shareLinkContentBuilder.Build();
                sb.ShareContent = shareLinkContent;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The share dialog opens and asks me to right something as I supposed to. However, the content does not appear and when I share they do not show. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fugired this out; first the SetImageUrl should be a valid url with an Image and second I needed to SetContentUrl also, otherwise it would empty the content.